# How to declare my iOS voip app as an option on contact info (like whatsApp)?

Tags: ios, voip, addressbook

I want to add my app in the contact info in the address book for messaging, video calls.

[image]

Comment: You are confusing number labels with app functionality.

Comment: @Desdenova I did not understand you, but what I want to do is exactly as WhatsApp adds their icon in the details of a contact so that you can launch the call directly from here

Comment: Try registering URL scheme . The contacts might recognize your app as someone who can handle the call URL scheme then you need to handle the URL in your App Delegate. Check the link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH6-SW1

Comment: @Wiss did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

This functionality can be achieve using [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit), in short CallKit provides native phone app UI to all the VoIP application, to let your app visible in the contact (after integrating the CallKit), you just need to smoothly long press the audio/video call buttons.

By default It shows the most frequent used app (say WhatsApp), once you'll long press the icons it'll show a list of the supporting apps (VoIP enable apps). From where you can choose the app to perform the action.

The screenshots will make you more sense to figure it out.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh5Y0.png)  - is the default situation I.e. default call and video option.

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuDlV.png) - Long press the call option, It’ll show all the apps which are capable to make audio call.

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQwA1.png) - Same for the video option.

[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPMgv.png) - Once you’ll use any app (suppose WhatsApp) the default icon will change to WhatsApp and in the list it’ll start showing WhatsApp and other concern apps.

Source: #1 [Ray Wenderlich Toutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/150015/callkit-tutorial-ios) , #2 [Sample Code of CallKit Objective-C & Swift both](https://github.com/naandonov-mm/iOS-10-Sampler/tree/master/CallKit)

Note: - In the list below it’ll start showing the apps name once you use any app to make call. And it’ll remain listed even if you uninstall that particular app.

Comment: How can I get the contact details with number when user place a call from voip app (like whatsapp) ? Once user is navigated to app, I need the details for selected call.

Comment: Showing my app's icon on call button is fine. But when i long press on message icon, it shows whatsapp there, How can i put my app there in that list in message option.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using CallKit. So adding  .phoneNumber to supportedHandleTypes gives this ability that you can call number via your application.

.generic also gives ability you can start call from history that made or received via your application.

```
  let config = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "anyname you want")
  config.supportedHandleTypes = [.phoneNumber,.generic]
```